# Add a second RulesAction to a custom module

Tags: 8, rules, actions

I created a custom module containing one Rules Action that works perfectly. I tried adding a second by creating a second php file in the `MODULE/src/Plugin/RulesAction` folder, with the names and class etc all changed from the original action.

I've tried refreshing the cache, and uninstalling/installing the module but the new action is not showing up. Is there another step I need to take, other than just putting a new file in the `MODULE/src/Plugin/RulesAction` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, it's right there under a different subheading. I expected them to appear together, but I set a different value on this line:

`*   category = @Translation("This is the heading the action appears under."),`